# Shopify app didn't reinstall successfully due to the 404 error

Tags: session, oauth, shopify, shopify-api, remix.run

I am developing a Shopify app.

When I installed the developed app, the installation was completed successfully.
When I uninstalled the app, the uninstallation was completed successfully.
When I try to install the app again, an error occurs.

Error
"404 There's no page at this address
Check the URL and try again, or use the search bar to find what you need."

NG Flow
( Partners Dashboard ) Login
01 Apps
02 MY_DEV_APP
03 Test your app / Select Store
04 MY_DEV_STORE Selected
( Page transition ) MY_DEV_STORE Login
05 Install Submit
Success
06 Uninstall Submit
Success
07 Settings
08 Apps and sales channels
09 (tab) Uninstalled
10 MY_DEV_APP
11 Install Submit
Error (log-1)
"404 There's no page at this address
Check the URL and try again, or use the search bar to find what you need."

OK Flow
( Partners Dashboard ) Login　
01 Apps
02 MY_DEV_APP
03 Test your app / Select Store
04 MY_DEV_STORE Selected
( Page transition ) MY_DEV_STORE Login
05 Install Submit
Success
06 Uninstall Submit
Success
( Partners Dashboard ) Login
07 Apps
08 MY_DEV_APP
09 Test your app / Select Store
10 MY_DEV_STORE Selected
( Page transition ) MY_DEV_STORE Login
11 Install Submit
Success

If you install by changing pages, the installation will be successful.

I'm a beginner in app development, so this may be a simple question, but I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me.

Thank you.

Development environment
Shopify Create a new app
javascript, Remix
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix
npm init @shopify/app@latest

Basically, use the default.
In particular, parts related to authorization such as OAuth have not been changed.

I thought it was a session issue, so I checked the database records.

```
model Session {
  id          String    @id
  shop        String
  state       String
  isOnline    Boolean   @default(false)
  scope       String?
  expires     DateTime?
  accessToken String
  userId      BigInt?
}
```

Records are added to installs and removed to uninstalls.
Reinstallation fails even though there is no information in the record.

The log in case of error is

```
[Server]
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `this.getSessionTable().upsert()` invocation in
~node_modules/@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma/build/cjs/prisma.js:27:34

  24 async storeSession(session) {
  25   await this.ready;
  26   const data = this.sessionToRow(session);
→ 27   await this.getSessionTable().upsert(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `PRIMARY`
    at ai.handleRequestError (~node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:126:6775)
    at ai.handleAndLogRequestError 
    (~node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:126:6109)
    at ai.request (~node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:126:5817)
    at l (~node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:131:9709)
    at PrismaSessionStorage.storeSession 
    (~node_modules/@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma/build/cjs/prisma.js:27:5)
    at TokenExchangeStrategy.authenticate 
    (~node_modules/@shopify/shopify-app-remix/build/cjs/server/authenticate/admin/strategies/token-exchange.js:49:7)
    at Object.authenticateAdmin [as admin] 
    (~node_modules/@shopify/shopify-app-remix/build/cjs/server/authenticate/admin/authenticate.js:107:23)
    at loader (~app/routes/app._index.jsx:40:3)
    at Object.callRouteLoaderRR 
    (~node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/data.js:52:16)
    at callLoaderOrAction (~node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:4020:16) {
  code: 'P2002',
  clientVersion: '5.9.1',
  meta: { modelName: 'Session', target: 'PRIMARY' }
}
```

```
[Browser]
webSocket connection to ' ... ' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I thought it might be a redirect URL, but I couldn't find any settings like that.